# How to prevent Jekyll from generating closing tag for the source element?

Tags: html, tags, markdown, jekyll, static-site

The MDN docs state the following on the `<source>` html element;

> The  HTML element specifies multiple media resources for the , the  element, or the  element. It is a void element, meaning that it has no content and does not have a closing tag.

However, Jekyll generates a closing `</source>` tags which isn't correct according to the docs.

I have the following in my template:

```
<source src="{{ item.gif-mp4 }}" type="video/mp4" />
```

Which generates:

```
<source src="/assets/uploads/the-blade.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

How do I resolve this?

I tried using a different markdown processor like redcarpet, which according to their docs should be able to remove the tags, but Jekyll won't work with that it says.

UPDATE: The following is more context:

```html
<video-js
      class="vjs-fluid"
      data-setup='{"controls": false, "preload": "auto", "muted": true, "autoplay": false, "loop": false, "playsinline": true}'
      poster="{{ item.image }}">
      <source src="{{ item.gif-webm }}" type="video/webm" />
      <source src="{{ item.gif-mp4 }}" type="video/mp4" />
      <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports html5 video</p>
</video-js>
```

I also tried without the `/>`, so just `>`

```
<source src="{{ item.gif-webm }}" type="video/webm">
<source src="{{ item.gif-mp4 }}" type="video/mp4">
```

But this gave me an even weirder output which put the closing source tags behind the paragraph:

```html
<video-js
  class="vjs-fluid"
  data-setup='{"controls": false, "preload": "auto", "muted": true, "autoplay": false, "loop": false, "playsinline": true}'
  poster="/assets/uploads/poster.jpg">
  <source src="/assets/uploads/video.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="/assets/uploads/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <p class="vjs-no-js">
    To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web
    browser that supports html5 video
  </p>
</source>
</source>
</video-js>
```

Notice the source tags after the paragraph and also the `/>` in the opening tag.

I do like to note however that the browser deletes these closing tags and the production site shows no errors but it still is weird and also the [validator.org](https://validator.w3.org/) does notice all the errors.

Comment: Which jekyll version are you using? also, add your config yml file to your post,

Comment: The reason this problem is occurring is because your template is being parsed to xhtml instead of html.

Comment: I found the problem. It was caused by the plugin 'jekyll-loading-lazy'. After I uninstalled it the source tags where removed correctly. Also I had the issue where I ended up with both of these meta tags: ```<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">```  Even though I only had the ```<meta charset="utf-8">``` in my template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was caused by the plugin 'jekyll-loading-lazy'. Which also caused some other problems in my code for example it rendered both of these meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Even though I only had

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

In my template.

Hope this might help others with weird problems!

Answer (score 0):

The correct tag should be:

```html
<source src="{{ item.gif-mp4 }}" type="video/mp4">
```

Notice there's no slash `/` after `type="video/mp4"`.

Comment: Tried that already, it didn't work. Should have mentioned that.